# Introductory Overlay Issue

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In sample app, able to see an issue with the Introductory overlay.
Steps to reproduce
1. Open the app with connecting to ChromeCast Receiver
2. Introductory Overlay will be visible with cast icon on top
3. Exit the app using the home button
4. Relaunch the app. Introductory overlay is visible now but without the cast icon

Please find the attached screenshots.
[image: Image with cast icon on initial launch]
[image: Image with missing cast icon]
Is there a way to solve this issue. I am using the sdk version 9.8.0 in my app and in that also the issue is visible.

Comment: Please open a ticket on the SDK tracker at https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list

Comment: Sure. Meanwhile is there a way to override this behaviour.?And also is it necessary to show the introductory overlay in apps?

Comment: Issue is created in the forum https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=1061